# Specific data mining using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, data-mining

I'm trying to build a program that would take the page source from a website and only store a snippet of code.

```
package Program;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String site = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4OUBG/ref=s9_ri_gw_g63_ir01?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-5&pf_rd_r=0GJRXWMKNC5559M5W2GB&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=394918607&pf_rd_i=468294";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(site);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

So far this will only display the code in the output. I would like the program to search for a specific string and display only the price.
e.g.

```
<tr id="actualPriceRow">
<td id="actualPriceLabel" class="priceBlockLabelPrice">Price:</td>
<td id="actualPriceContent"><span id="actualPriceValue"><b class="priceLarge">£599.99</b></span>
<span id="actualPriceExtraMessaging">
```

search for `class="priceLarge">` and only display/store 599.99

I know that there are similar questions on the website however I don't really understand any php and would like a java solution although any solution is welcome :)

Comment: SO what have your tried in searching for the price? What did you have trouble with?

Comment: While you might be able to do this with a regular expression, you should really use an xml/html parsing library. learning that will save you a lot of effort in the future if you are interested in web programming

Comment: Since this is HTML, maybe you'll have an easier time using jsoup.

Comment: +1 for Jsoup, you can **easily** do everything you need with the CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some library for parsing eg. Jsoup

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4OUBG/ref=s9_ri_gw_g63_ir01?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-5&pf_rd_r=0GJRXWMKNC5559M5W2GB&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=394918607&pf_rd_i=468294").get();
```

then you can search for concrete element

```
Elements el = document.select("b.priceLarge");
```

and then you can get content of this element like

```
String content = el.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote in a question edit:

> Thank you all for responses it was really helpful and here is the answer:
>
> ```
> package Project;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
> import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
>
> public class Project {
>
> /**
>  * @param args the command line arguments
>  */
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     Document doc;
>     try {
>         doc = Jsoup.connect("url of link").get();
>         String title = doc.title();
>         System.out.println("title : " + title);
>         String pricing = doc.getElementsByClass("priceLarge").text();
>         String str = pricing;
>         str = str.substring(1);
>         System.out.println("price : " + str);
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         System.out.println(e);
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: ([answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))